# WCFstreaming issue when setting position to 0

Tags: wcf, stream

On a `WCF` rest service I am dealing with streams. In a service method I am uploading a stream in a `data contract` which works fine. And on service side I process the stream and its position is now at `eof`. After doing that I need to set its position to `0` again therefore I can save it there. But it throws the exception:

> > Specified method is not supported.

Does it mean I can't process a stream more then once? If it does I will need a workaround for that :/ and only solution pops into my mind is sending the stream two times so I can process it separately, but it is not good since I would have to upload it twice.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny that I found my own solution :) first I saved the stream, then read it from that path for further processes over that stream. its interesting that finding the solution didn't require more detailed, technical information but a change of logical approach.